# [].append(x) behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x

This executes as I'd expect:

```
>>>x=[]
>>>x.append(3)
>>>x
[3]
```

Why does the following return None?

```
>>>x = [].append(3)
>>>x
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is "why is `x` `None`?", then it's because `list.append` returns `None` as others say.

If the question is "why was `append` designed to return `None` instead of `self`?" then ultimately it is because of Guido van Rossum's decision, which he explains here as it applies to a related case:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html

> I'd like to explain once more why I'm so adamant that sort() shouldn't
>   return 'self'.
>
> This comes from a coding style (popular in various other languages, I
>   believe especially Lisp revels in it) where a series of side effects
>   on a single object can be chained like this:
>
> `x.compress().chop(y).sort(z)`
>
> which would be the same as
>
> `x.compress()` 
>     `x.chop(y)` 
>     `x.sort(z)`
>
> I find the chaining form a threat to readability;

In short, he doesn't like methods that return `self` because he doesn't like method chaining. To prevent you from chaining methods like `x.append(3).append(4).append(5)` he returns `None` from `append`.

I speculate that this could perhaps be considered a specific case of the more general principle that distinguishes between:

- pure functions, that have no side-effects and return values
- procedures, that have side-effects and do not return values

Of course the Python language doesn't make any such distinction, and the Python libraries do not apply the general principle. For example `list.pop()` has a side-effect and returns a value, but since the value it returns isn't (necessarily) `self` it doesn't violate GvR's more specific rule.

Answer (score 8):

because `list.append` changes the list itself and returns `None` ;)

You can use `help` to see the docstring of a function or method:

```
In [11]: help(list.append)
Help on method_descriptor:

append(...)
    L.append(object) -- append object to end
```

### EDIT:

This is explained in [docs of python3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types):

*Some collection classes are mutable. The methods that add, subtract, or rearrange 
their members in place, and don’t return a specific item, never return the 
collection instance itself but `None`.*

Comment: which bit of that snippet shows that None is returned ...`(...)` ?

Comment: @whytheq the docstring would say `do sth. and return sth.` if it does return something. See `help(list.pop)` as a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The `append` method of lists returns `None`. It only modifies the list it is bounded to. Same will happen with:

```
x = {}.update(a=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The method [`list.append()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) changes the list *inplace*, and returns no result (so returns None if you prefer)

Many methods of list work on the list inplace, so you doesn't need to reassign a new list to override the old one.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> id(lst)
4294245644L
>>> lst.append(1)
>>> id(lst)
4294245644L   # <-- same object, doesn't change.
```

With `[].append(1)`, you're adding 1 to a list freshly created, and you have no reference on this one. So once the `append` is done, you have lost the list (and will be collected by the garbage collector).
By the way, fun fact, to make sense to my answer:

```
>>> id([].append(1))
1852276280
>>> id(None)
1852276280
```

Comment: +1 nice - like the weird addition proving that the garbage collector found your None list.