# Simple function to reverse a list

Tags: python, list, recursion

Using the `+` operator works fine. If I try to write using the `append` method it returns `None`.

Can `revFromEnd2` reverse the list using the `append` method?

```
def revFromEnd(L):
    if len(L)==1:
        return L
    else:
        return [L[-1]] + revFromEnd(L[:-1])

def revFromEnd2(L):
    if len(L)==1:
        return L
    else:
        return [L[-1]].append(revFromEnd2(L[:-1]))

print(revFromEnd([1,2,3,4,5]))
print()
print(revFromEnd2([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: Maybe you should use this?
reversed([1, 2, 3])

Comment: Why not simply step through the list backwards? `return L[::-1]`?

Comment: I was just about to ask why not use L[::-1], you beat me to it.

Comment: You already asked a very related question yesterday: [`[].append(x)` behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21931092/2225682). Please read answers there again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.append` appends an item to the list in place and **returns nothing** (= return `None`), unlike `+` operator which return new list concatenating two lists:

```
>>> [1, 2] + [3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [1, 2].append(3) # => None
>>>
```

BTW, you'd better use `list.extend` considering that `recvFromEnd1/2` return `list`:

```
>>> lst = [1,2]
>>> lst.append([3,4])
>>> lst
[1, 2, [3, 4]] # <--- Is this what you want?


>>> lst = [1,2]
>>> lst.extend([3,4])
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

```
def revFromEnd2(L):
    if len(L)==1:
        return L
    else:
        ret = [L[-1]]
        ret.extend(revFromEnd2(L[:-1]))
        return ret
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `list.append` appends to the list in place. `a = [1, 2, 3]; a.append(4); a == [1, 2, 3, 4];`.

Comment: @sweeneyrod, Thank you for comment. I added a mention about in-place append.

Comment: @sweeneyrod the `==` does not check if append is inplace

Comment: @sweeneyrod That's not the real proof of the point that `append` is in place.  More something like `a = b = [1, 2]; id(a) == id(b); a.append(3); id(a) == id(b)`.

Comment: The `a == [1, 2, 3, 4]` was more just to show how `append` works, a shortcut for "and now `a` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`". On another subject, why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: @downvoter: How can I improve the answer?  I just wanted to let the OP why he/she got the unexpected result. I know there's better options like `reversed`, `seq[::-1]`, but it is already mentioned by jcdenton; I don't want to duplicate it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in function `reversed`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(reversed(l))
[3, 2, 1]
```

You could also use slices (their syntax is [start:end:step], so if you define a negative value for step, it would make a slice in opposite direction):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

UPD: Yes, recursion is great, but since you're using Python and [it doesn't optimize tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion), it'd be better to use more obvious methods :)

Comment: Thanks for extra points although not really addressing the question - to reverse the list recursively was simply a basic exercise in recursion - so using `reversed` misses the point.