# Overwriting builtins python class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, built-in

What I am looking for is a way to do that in python 2.7

```
oldlist = list
class list(oldlist):
    def append(self, object):
        super(list, self).append(object)
        return self
    def sort(self, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False):
        super(list, self).sort(cmp, key, reverse)
        return self
__builtins__.list=list
print list([3, 4, 1, 2]).append(5)
print list([3, 4, 1, 2]).append(5).sort()
print list([3, 4, 1, 2]).append(5).sort(reverse=True)
print list([3, 4, 1, 2]).append(5).sort()[0]
print [3, 4, 1, 2].append(5)
print [3, 4, 1, 2].append(5).sort()
print [3, 4, 1, 2].append(5).sort(reverse=True)
print [3, 4, 1, 2].append(5).sort()[0]
```

Actually print :

```
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
1
None
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Should print :

```
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
1
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
1
```

I know it can be dangerous to edit builtins class, but some methods really return nothing, do a python script actually expect them to return something, so what the problem ?

For now I think that much simple to do :

```
filterfiles(myfilelist.sort())
```

than doing :

```
myfilelist.sort()    
filterfiles(myfilelist)
```

And it permit to see the results when in interactive mode (instead of nothing)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3 here? I am assuming 3 for now.

Comment: Note that over-riding `__builtins__.dict` only affects the use of `dict`... it won't affect the dict literals such as `{1:1, 2:2}` - they'll still be the builtin dicts regardless... You'd have to be explicit and use `yourdictname({1: 1, 2:2})`

Comment: There is indeed little point in overriding `dict` here if you expect dictionary literals to be affected too. Since they are not, you may as well just make it explicit and use your subclass everywhere instead.

Comment: I'm using Python 2, I've updated the post.
Overiting builtin literal dict is what I want. I know I can do something like
    print(dict({1: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1})+{2: 2, 3: 2, 5: 2})
But I really like to make my lines shorten as posible.

Comment: *but somes methods return nothing and I would like them returning themself* - that's fine, but it's not how the rest of the data strcutures in Python work. Using `+` to mutate the current object is just  going to confuse a lot of people. You could use `+=` here, but I think most people would be surprised that for a mutable object it returns an object instead of `None`.

Comment: A simple example of what I want 
code.InteractiveConsole(globals().copy()+locals()).interact()

Comment: @y.petremann If making lines shorter is your main goal, I understand that it is one-shot code, that no one is going to read in future (including you in few weeks)?

Comment: @y.petremann you can't over-ride dictionary literals... You have to explicitly call them with your class: `mydict({1: 1, 2:2})` - there's no way to make `{1:1, 2:2}` automatically be an instance of `mydict` (short of hacking the parser)

Comment: @y.petremann: In that case I'd use `dict(globals(), **locals())` anyway.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is that when we put {1:1, 2:2}, python look for making the dict literal into a dict object, and I know I can't change python to make an instance of mydict, but is there a way to change the builtins dict directly, whereas it use somes hacky way ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank for that point, I doesn't know we could do that and could help me a lot, but since that was an example, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @y.petremann: The reason I tell you is that your usecase is pretty flimsey to begin with. Replacing built-ins like this is generally also a great source of hard-to-trace bugs. And since these are comments, please do take this as they are intended: as *advice*, not answers.

Comment: But seriously. Don't replace built-in types. They're called **built-in** for a reason. Make your own class that behaves like you want it to, and use it.

Comment: Use `filterfiles(sorted(myfilelist))`. These methods return `None` by design: In this case, to avoid inadvertently sorting a list in-place when you really want a sorted copy. Python already provides functional alternatives for such cases (like `sorted()`) when it makes sense to.

Answer (score 2):

> One thing I don't understand is that when we put `{1:1, 2:2}`, python look for making the dict literal into a dict object, and I know I can't change python to make an instance of mydict, but is there a way to change the builtins dict directly, whereas it use somes hacky way?

No, it’s simply not possible. Literals, that means any literal (strings, numbers, lists, dicts), are part of the Python syntax. The objects they represent are created from the parser at a very low level, long before you can change anything with Python code.

There is another important thing though. The built-in objects are all implemented in native code; they don’t actually exist as Python objects in the Python environment. For that purpose, things like `__builtins__.dict` provides a reference *to* the native dictionary type. When the objects are created with literals, the real native type is used though, so `__builtins__.dict` is never accessed. As such, changing `__builtins__.dict` will not affect it at all. It will only change the environment, where these references actually matter.

You can imagine this situation like this:

```
# native code
class _InternalSpecialType:
    pass
def makeSpecialType (): # this is our “literal” evaluator
    return _InternalSpecialType()

# public interface
SpecialType = _InternalSpecialType

# then in the Python code
class NewSpecialType(SpecialType):
    pass
SpecialType = NewSpecialType

# using a “literal”
x = makeSpecialType()
print(type(x)) # _InternalSpecialType
```

So no, you can’t change what the literal uses under the hood. It’s simply impossible. If you want to have an object of a different type, you will always have to create it explicitely. And then it’s best to name the type differently than the original type to avoid confusion (and incompatibility between the changed type and literals).

And finally, about methods of built-in types not allowing chaining: Just live with it. Guido knowingly decided against it, and usually, Guido has good reasons you can trust, so it’s likely for the better (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21932208/216074)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've always though that python was sufficiently "modular" to making possible to change the type of literals, maybe making new type of literals, but I was wrong. also I never seen the problem about chaining and readability, for me it was for some unknown reason like optimizing the python source code, making it lighter and faster ...

Comment: Python is sufficiently modular to allow you to rebind `list` and other built-ins _without_ affecting the behavior of literals and other modules.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain how to solve the problem you have, rather than how to implement the solution you're after:

Write `filterfiles(sorted(myfilelist))`.

Methods that return `None` do so by design: In this case, to avoid inadvertently sorting a list in-place (and losing its current ordering) when you really wanted a sorted copy. Python already provides functional alternatives for such cases, like `sorted()` in this case, when it makes sense to. Note that `sorted()` does not modify its argument.

If you do find a use case for which no functional alternative is provided, I would recommend you get around it in the same way: Write a function (not method) that returns what you want to see. (But check out python's `functools` module first).